# Name editor in Java

Tags: java

While working on an assignment in class, with the goal to take a First and Last name, and change the Format to "LastName, FirstName"(using subnamel&subnamef)(without an Array!!!). I have ran into an issue however.

```
String name="",subnamef="",subnamel="";
    System.out.println("Enter name->");
    name = scan.next();
    char space = ' ';
    if(name.indexOf(space)!=-1){
        name = name.replace(space, ',');
        int placehold = name.indexOf(',');
        subnamef = name.substring(0,placehold );
        subnamel = name.substring(placehold);
        name = subnamel+", "+subnamef;
        }
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

The output now just says the first name without the last name or the comma
Is there an easier route than the way I am attempting this problem? If not, please advise on how to make the current method work.

Comment: What will happen if input string dosen't have any spaces. The said exception is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harvey, I would suggest trying something simple like the code below for your testing.  This may be easier to work with than running your test my typing data in from the keyboard each time.

For simple debugging I find it very helpful to add some print statements to my code and see what is happening.
Here is a short test class:
Just for fun, what kind of values were you using as your test input(s)?
Go ahead and add those inputs and see if you can get the code to run.

Pretty much 90% of this is your original code, I just added some print statements.  Let me know how it works for you.

Also... because you are a student in a class I wanted to suggest a hint or nudge towards a solution to help you grow your debugging and troubleshooting skills, not to simply fix this one problem for you.

Good luck and have fun programming :-)

Example output:
Note that it blows up on the first test with an empty string.
Make that work and run it again until it succeeds on all of your inputs.

```
$ javac NameTest.java 
$ java NameTest
----- testName(): name=<>
testName(): placehold=-1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at NameTest.testName(NameTest.java:24)
    at NameTest.main(NameTest.java:3)
$
```

Simple test setup:

```
public class NameTest {
   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      testName( "" );
      testName( "donald,tramp" );
      testName( "tramp,donald" );
      testName( "donald tramp" );
      testName( "tramp donald" );
   }

   public static void testName( String name ) {
      String subnamef="",subnamel="";
      //System.out.println("Enter name->");
      System.out.println("----- testName(): name=<"+name+">");0
      //name = scan.next();
      char space = ' ';
      if(name.indexOf(space)!=-1){
         name.replace(space, ',');
         System.out.println("testName(): replacing space, after: name=<"+name+">");
      }
      int placehold = name.indexOf(',');
      System.out.println("testName(): placehold="+placehold);

      // So... what do you want to do if placehold is -1 ?
      subnamef = name.substring(0,placehold );
      System.out.println("testName(): subnamef="+subnamef);
      subnamel = name.substring(placehold);
      System.out.println("testName(): subnamel="+subnamel);

      String name2 = subnamel+", "+subnamef;
      System.out.println("intput:  name=<"+name+">");
      System.out.println("result: name2=<"+name2+">");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for directing me and not just giving me a solution!

Comment: Harvey, you are welcome :-)  I have a lot of fun programming, once you get a little ways up the java learning curve it should start to feel like less work and more fun.  I'm also a fan of small steps and taking time to digest and absorb.  *shrug* just how I learn.  Anyway, keep at it - your initial logic looked pretty reasonable, just some edge conditions to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is that the replace method returns your result, it doesn't directly perform the replace operation on the string.
Instead of

```
name.replace(space, ',');
```

put

```
name = name.replace(space, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 changes which I can think of:

```
System.out.println("Enter name->");
// 1st Change: Read a line instead of single token
String name = scan.nextLine();
char space = ' ';
int placehold = name.indexOf(space);
if (placehold != -1) {
    // 2nd Change: No need to replace. Simple space check will also work
    // 3rd change: moving the code inside if block.
    // Do operation only if input contains spaces
    String subnamef = name.substring(0, placehold);
    String subnamel = name.substring(placehold);
    name = subnamel + ", " + subnamef;
}
System.out.println(name.trim());
```

Comment: I changed the if statement to the way how you have it, however now it just outputs the first name without the last name or the comma. I will edit question again. Thanks